# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi my dynamic web application in struts1 spring and hibernate integration is developed on 64 bit machine..Its running fine on 64 bit machine but giving jar issues on 32 bit machine its giving following error

```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
```

and

```
    SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
```

should i change all jars for 32 bit machine?

Comment: This is not related to platform architecture, but some configuration problem. What servlet container you are using? Apache Tomcat?

Comment: Why is this tagged `hibernate`?

Answer (score 3):

I had some similar problem in when i tried to compile one project without the servlet dependancy, if you use maven put the javax.servlet in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can change the version to another if you know the version target and the scope is *provided* because is probably that you will use tomcat or another type of server, that contain already the implementation

Or if you not use maven, you can download the .jar and add to the lib folder of your projet

Answer (score 0):

You just do not have Spring (totally or partially) in your classpath at runtime. It seems that `Log4jConfigListener` is the first class referenced when you try to load your application. Take care on copying all needed jar files to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.