# Why can't Eclipse find javax.servlet.ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat6

I know it is a question that was already asked many times, but I tried almost all the solutions I found and it still does not work.

I'm working with:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Java 7
- Maven
- Tomcat 6.0.37

I'm trying to start the serverbut it fails because of :

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Jul 13, 2015 3:30:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more

Jul 13, 2015 3:30:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more

Jul 13, 2015 3:30:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 29 more
```

The first time I imported the project, the startup succeeded and the application was successful. But then it did not work anymore so I created a new workspace and I imported the project a second time in that new workspace, and that's where I got those errors.

What I already tried so far :

- use Tomcat installation instead of workspace metadata
- [ClassNotFoundException with ServletContextlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849452/classnotfoundexception-with-servletcontextlistener)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180880/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-servletcontextlistener-error)
- a lot of project/clean, Maven/update project, Server/clean
- server/open launch configuration -> I added `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` and `spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar` to the classpath under `User entries`
- when I was using workspace metadata, I also tried to copy and paste WEB-INF folder in the .plugin folder of metadata
- I also checked if the jars are in the .m2 folder and it seems to be ok

Edit: 
@Gimby
My application is not yet deployed so I don't have any war file. But I do have a lib folder under WEB-INF : 
apache-tomcat-6.0.37\wtpwebapps\msapp-web\WEB-INF\lib
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are the libraries in the apache Tomcat of the Build Path:
[image]

Comment: What libraries are in the WEB-INF/lib of your application's deployed war file?

Comment: Can you Open the Type `ServletContextListener` from inside Eclipse? Which jar file is it coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are getting this error because your trying to start tomcat server from Eclipse. So, the problem lies with how Eclipse configures the Classpath for a WebApp.

In Eclipse, go to the Project's "properties" window.
Select:
Java Build Path > Libraries.

Select: 
Server Runtime> Apache Tomcat.

This will tell Eclipse that it should consider Tomcat's lib director jars are part of the classpath for Tomcat.

Comment: I do have Apache Tomcat v6.0 [Apache Tomcat v6.0] in my Java Build Path

Comment: I don't see the servlet-api.jar in the screen caps you have attached. Does the Build Path entry (for Apache Tomcat) expand to show the Jars in the tomcat/lib directory?

Comment: Yes it is in the Apache Tomcat buildpath, I've just edited my post and added a screenshot.

Comment: how is Tomcat being started?

Comment: I usually do Right click/start on the Server

Comment: I wonder if "Deployment Assembly" is something to be looked at.

Comment: Also..  try  remove the server from the list of servers. remove the build path entry.  Restart Eclipse. and Re Add the server and build path entry.

Comment: I removed the server and added it, so it helped me get another error which is easier to solve, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

I did a lot of clean, refresh, even removing the server and re-adding it. I also did : right click on the project /Maven / Update project

What happened is the

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

disappeared. Indeed, I don't have any errors anymore but the server started so quickly that it is obvious that none of the pages has been loaded. Because I can see the loading logs in the console when the pages are really bein loaded. This was not a case and I got a

> http status 404

After that, I did several times

> right click on the server/Properties/Switch location

I then had another errors related to database connection :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource

Therefore, I implemented the second proposal of @Ranger

[Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065974/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver)

which consists of adding the

> ojdbc14.jar

to the classpath of the run configuration, under

> User entries

And then it worked ...

I don't know if it is Maven or Eclipse or Tomcat that is this much unstable with detecting libraries. 
Anyway it worked, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tomcat10, then you have to use `jakarta.servlet` instead of `javax.servlet` in your maven/gradle dependencies.

I posted more detailed explanation in: [ServletContextListener not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367514/servletcontextlistener-not-being-invoked/67483205#67483205)

Tomcat10 will not invoke listener classes that use `javax.servlet`, which is extremely confusing, since all tutorials and stack-overflow guides will tell you to use `javax.servlet` maven dependency, but that is exactly why Listners don't get called in Tomcat10.